# Using RestSharp to aend files between to API's on Kubernetes

Tags: asp.net, kubernetes, restsharp

So I have to API's running on Kubernetes. One has a controller function as such:

```
string filePath = "/blobs/data/runsession/" + folderName;
if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
    return null;

var tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), guid.ToString());
logger.Info("GetTempPath()" + Path.GetTempPath());
logger.Info("Temp path is: " + tempFile);
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filePath, (tempFile + ".zip"));

byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(tempFile + ".zip");

HelpMethods.GetNetworkTimeStamp("Stop", 2);

return fileBytes;
```

This controller method works fine and when I call it from postman it returns a file.

Now in the other API I want to call this function from one of my service classes as such:

```
public async Task<byte[]> DownloadRunSession(string foldername)
{
    try
       {
         var request = new RestRequest($"blob/{foldername}")
         {
             Timeout = -1,
         };

         var response = await client.ExecuteGetAsync(request);

         if (!response.IsSuccessful)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("File download failed");
             Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());
             return null;
          }

          return response.RawBytes;

      }catch(Exception e)
       {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
         Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
         return null;
       }
```

Now the server logs on the API that sends the file Give me a status 200 but says "the application aborted the connection", and the API that is supposed to receive the file gets no response and the response variable is always "null".

Any one that has had a similar dilemma and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#downloading-binary-data

Comment: RestSHarp documentation is really poor and has almost nothing on API to API communication. I did solve the issue however it was being cause by lack of allocated memory on the server that was running the API receiving the file this would cause the connection to be timed out.

Comment: RestSharp is an open-source project, so if you have suggestions about improving the documentation, you are free to make such improvements and make a pull request.

Comment: Stopped using it, just used AspNetCore.http. Gives a lot more freedom and control. The lack of documentation was a issue that I didn't have time to address.

Comment: I don't know what `AspNetCore.http` is but it's great that you have a solution.